# Loop Data Validation List

Tags: excel, vba

What I want to do is to loop data validation and when I find a match, select the option from data validation. Below is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Insert()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim str As String
    Dim rng As Range, Opt As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow

            str = .Range("A" & i).Value

            Set rng = Evaluate(.Range("B" & i).Validation.Formula1)

            For Each Opt In rng

                If Opt.Value = str Then
                    Opt.Select
                End If

            Next

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

I get a:

> Run time error '424'

on line: `Set rng = Evaluate(.Range("B" & i).Validation.Formula1)`

Typing: `?.Range("B" & i).Validation.Formula1` on the immediate window a get all the values from the data validation list.

Any help will be appreciate!

**Answer**

What i manage to do is the below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Insert()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, y As Long
    Dim str As String
    Dim arr As Variant, element As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow

            str = .Range("A" & i).Value

            arr = Split(.Range("B" & i).Validation.Formula1, ",")

            For y = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)

                If InStr(1, arr(y), str) > 0 Then
                    .Range("B" & i) = arr(y)
                    Exit For
                Else
                    .Range("B" & i).ClearContents
                End If

            Next y

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: So what does this equal `.Range("B" & i).Validation.Formula1` ?

Comment: @SJR just update the question to include the answer to your question :-)

Comment: Ok but what is the actual value when it errors?

Comment: Empty. I want to loop the different choices of the data validation in .range("B" & i) and select the one which includes the value in .range("A" & i)

Comment: I don't think it will be a range?  Try `? typename(rng)` see what type it is, may be just an array or string formula?

Comment: Think you need something like so `set rng=range(replace(.Range("B" & i).Validation.Formula1,"=",""))`

Comment: Also, no need for the 2nd loop if you're using a range, you have `worksheetfunction.match` to use.

Comment: i cant get rng type cause it generate's an error

Comment: If you've typed in a list to your DV that will error I think, so you need to have selected the items from a range.

Comment: And if selected from a range in the immediate window you would see the address of the range so my guess is you are using a typed list.

Answer (score 0):

`.Range("B" & i).Validation.Formula1` returns a `String` value. The `Error 424` is being raised by the `Set` keyword. If the list is typed, you'd need to split it into an array and loop through those elements.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Insert()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim str As String
    Dim dvArr
    Dim opt As Long

    With Worksheets("Report 11")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow

            str = .Range("A" & i).Value

            dvArr = Split(.Range("B" & i).Validation.Formula1, ",")

            For opt = LBound(dvArr) To UBound(dvArr)
                If dvArr(opt) = str Then
                    .Range("B" & i) = dvArr(opt)
                End If

            Next

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

If the list isn't typed then you can replace the `=` in the return string value to reference a range.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Insert()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim str As String
    Dim rng As Range, Opt As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow

            str = .Range("A" & i).Value

            set rng = .Range(Replace(.Range("B" & i).Validation.Formula1,"=",""))

            For Each Opt In rng

                If Opt.Value = str Then
                    .Range("B" & i) = Opt.Value
                End If

            Next

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works only for cells that have data validation set, and where `Formula1` contains a Range. 
The data validation has a property `Type` that tells you what kind of validation you are using. The list of types can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xldvtype

For your case (a list of value), this is type 3. So you should check if validation has type 3 before your assignment. Unfortunately, if no validation is set to a cell and you check the validation type, you will get a runtime error (1004).

This could be handled with a code like

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim hasValidation  As Boolean
hasValidation = (rng.Validation.Type = 3)
On Error GoTo 0
If hasValidation Then
    ....
```

I admit that this is not much better than to write

```
 On Error Resume Next
 set rng = Nothing
 set rng = Evaluate(.Range("B" & i).Validation.Formula1)

 On Error Goto 0
 if not rng is Nothing then
    ....
```

An alternative could be to loop only over those cells that have data validation

```
dim cell as range
For Each cell In .Range("B:B").EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    if cell.Validation.type = 3 Then
        set rng = Evaluate(cell.Validation.Formula1)
        ....
```

The trick with the `Evaluate` should work when the `Formula1` contains a `Range`, no need to tinker around with the string (to remove the `=` or stuff like that).

One last remark: In your original code, you just do a `Select` to the found value, but you continue with the loop that checks all cells having validation. You will have to make up your mind what should happen in the case you have multiple cells with data validation.